# How to remove field values from java to gson().tojson

Tags: gson

my json output displays field name in my json array.

[name:jimmy,surname:hat]

what do i need to do to return in this format with just the values.

[jimmy,hat]

Answer (score 1):

Typically if you have an array in your code, something like this:

```
class X {
    String[] y = new String[] { "a", "b", "c" }
}
```

Gson converts to:

```
{
    "y":["a","b","c"]
}
```

If your array is holding objects, i.e.

```
class Y {
    String name;
    String val;
}
class X {
    Y[] y; // some data
}
```

Gson converts to:

```
{
    "y":[{"name":"n1","val":"v1"},{"name":"n2","val":"v2"}]
}
```

So, if you want your array to be only values, just be sure it's an array of strings.